# JavaScript library for synchronization of data between clients and the node.js server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sandbox

Is there a JavaScript library that will take a particular data on server (say, an array) and automatically synchronize it between clients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Opa Framework](http://opalang.org/)

> the Opa Slicer automates the calls between client and server. No more manually written AJAX calls or value serialization!

See also:

- [Opa on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opa_%28programming_language%29)
- [Comparison on developer.com](http://www.developer.com/open/node.js-opa-javascript-framework.html)
- [Opa counter example](https://github.com/akoprow/hands-on-opa/blob/master/examples/counter/counter.opa)

## Functional Reactive Programming

For FRP in general:

- [Wikipedia on FRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming)
- [Functional reactive programming for the web, or: where’s my Lunascript?!](http://yz.mit.edu/wp/functional-reactive-programming-for-the-web-or-wheres-my-lunascript/) ([Reddit discicussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/im3z3/functional_reactive_programming_for_the_web_or/))

Examples of web FRP:

**New languages**:

- **[Ur/Web](http://www.impredicative.com/ur/)** ([Example of a counter](http://www.impredicative.com/ur/demo/counter.html), (no server sync in this example, but client view/model sync is the first step)
- **[Elm](http://elm-lang.org/)** (no counter but very similar [ZIP code example](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Reactive/ZipCodes.elm))
- **[Flapjax](http://www.flapjax-lang.org/)** (can't find an AJAX example, doesn't seem to focus on server sync)
- Possibly can also be realized at some point with **[Roy](http://roy.brianmckenna.org/)**
- Possibly can also be realized [at some point](https://github.com/boothead/fay-frp) with **[Fay](https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki)**

**Libraries for JavaScript**:

- **[Bacon.js](https://github.com/raimohanska/bacon.js)** ([Example of a counter in the Intro](https://github.com/raimohanska/bacon.js#intro))

## [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/)

FRP is still relatively experimental, so if you are building something large, I'd go with Angular.js [for reasons mentioned here](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/10/yesod-fay-js) and because it seems to have the right level of ambitiousness.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for :/

Comment: @Dokkat: you should have written a longer question then :) something like what you describe in the question can easily be built with Angular.js

Comment: Not that this is a bad answer, LunaScript looks awesome and Angular.js  is great, just that I was looking for a more direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like WebSockets might be what you're looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets

Otherwise, standard AJAX polling could probably do the job.

Comment: That's right but not exactly what I mean, I was actually asking if there's a lib for automatic synchronization of objects, without having to do it manually via websockets, which could be laborous.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it fits your need but you could try [jIO](http://www.j-io.org/)([Github](http://github.com/nexedi/jio)) which can sync JSON documents across different storages.

So in your case you would have your array on the server and every client using a replicate revision storage setup (local storage/remote server storage). JIO will keep client-server in sync, so when a user updates the array the server array will also be updated. Conflicts (different versions existing on a client) will be raised, so you would have to write you own handler on how to solve conflicts (= take the latest array, remove the other one, for example).

JIO works similar to [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

Of course you could also have a look at [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/)

Comment: hm. haven't thought about that yet. JIO is using POST/PUT/GET/REMOVE and PUT/GET/REMOVE ATTACHEMENT. So on the client you would GET when the application loads (or whenever you trigger a `your_jio.get({"_id":"file_id"},function(err, resp) {console.log(resp = your file);})`. So either don't call POST/PUT from the client (then client cannot change the received file) or you remove the commands from the client-side js file altogether. Then the commands don't exists either. Let me know if you have any other questions.